# Can I load the columns (each series) one by one in a HighChart JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using HighCharts JS for making a bubble chart. It's a pretty self-explanatory but what I am trying to do is a changed mechanism.

the graph loads the chart perfectly, but it loads all the columns (or series) at the same time. What I am hoping to do is that it loads each column one-by-one.

You can see the example graph at this link:- 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble

As you can see in the sample graph shown above, they have three series, and they all load simultaneously; I was hoping that it loads one-by-one.

Any idea,

Thanks.

Comment: So which chart should be animatated in other way bubble or column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove series from options, and add all of them in load event. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qc8bS/

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this;

                function addSeries() {
                    if (s.length > 0) {
                        chart.addSeries(s[0]);
                        setTimeout(addSeries, 1000);
                        s.splice(0, 1);
                    }
                }

                addSeries();
            }
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
    },

    series: []

});
```